# How to disable/enable mouse click in whole application depending upon existence of angular material toast message in application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Below is my code. Is there any other way for disabling and enabling mouse click depending on existence if toast message ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { disableFullScreen } from '@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastService {

  constructor(private toastMsg: MatSnackBar) { }

  showToastMsg(message: string): void {

    this.toastMsg.open(message, 'close');
    if (this.toastMsg.open(message, 'close')) {
      window.document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    } else {
      window.document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mouse click will be disabled until toast message will be on. If close button in toast message will be clicked, then mouse click will be enabled in application.

Comment: Got my solution. Thank you all